# Three levels of Routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

[Plunkr for 3 Levels of Menu](https://plnkr.co/edit/xf5C1JXHQtmkthpnBzy9?p=preview)

I am trying to have 3 levels of Menu, but can't seem to get it right

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', component: PagesComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
        { path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component, outlet: 'leftMenu'},
        { path: 'Page1/Page1Child1', component: Page1Child1Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'},
        { path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component, outlet: 'leftMenu'}
    ], { enableTracing: true })
```

From the Left Menu, I want to load the selected page in the content(center of the page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sQ1bACpDvzYZgvYmA0mq?p=preview)

I made several changes.

A component can't only have named outlets. Exactly one outlet has to be unnamed. `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` (in `src/app.html`)

I completed the routes (and changed them to all-lowercase but that might not be necessary - I did it just to prevent case errors)

```ts
RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: PagesComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component, outlet: 'leftMenu'},
            { path: 'page1/page1child1', component: Page1Child1Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'},
            { path: 'page1/page1child2', component: Page1Child2Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'},
            { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component, outlet: 'leftMenu'},
            { path: 'page2/page2child1', component: Page2Child1Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'},
            { path: 'page2/page2child2', component: Page2Child2Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'},
        ]
```

I changed the router lins for the content components to

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {contentOutlet: item.url}}]" routerLinkActive="active" >{{item.display}}</a>
```

with the `links` array like

```ts
links: any[] = [
    { url: 'page1/page1child1', display: 'Page1Child1' },
    { url: 'page1/page1child2', display: 'Page1Child2' },
];
```